# Combining two SQL queries with multiple tables and left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there a way that I can combine these two queries:

FIRST QUERY

```
select top 100
WORK.pzInsKey,
WORK.pyID,
PARTY.MacID,
PARTY.OtherPartyID,
PARTY.CustomerEmail,
ACCOUNT.AccountNumber,
ACCOUNT.AccountName,
ACCOUNT.AdviserCode,
ACCOUNT.AdviserName,
ACCOUNT.DealerCode,
ACCOUNT.DealerName,
ACCOUNT.PrimaryAccount,
ACCOUNT.ProductCategory,
ACCOUNT.ProductCode,
ACCOUNT.ProductDescription,
ACCOUNT.RegisteredState,
DOCUMENT.UDOCID
from 
workTable WORK,
partyTable PARTY,
accountTable ACCOUNT,
documentTable DOCUMENT,
notesTable NOTES
where WORK.pzInsKey = PARTY.pxInsIndexedKey
and WORK.pzInsKey = ACCOUNT.pxInsIndexedKey
and WORK.pyID = DOCUMENT.CaseID
```

and SECOND QUERY

```
SELECT top 100 
BusinessAreaTbl.businessarea,
ProcessTbl.process,
SubProcessTbl.subprocess
FROM workTable WORK
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID businessarea_id, Product businessarea from CaseTypesTable) BusinessAreaTbl
ON WORK.RequestBusinessArea#1 = BusinessAreaTbl.businessarea_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Process_ID, Process, Product_ID businessarea_id from CaseTypesTable) ProcessTbl
ON WORK.RequestProcess#1 = ProcessTbl.process_id
AND ProcessTbl.businessarea_id = WORK.RequestBusinessArea#1

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SubProcess_ID, SubProcess, Product_ID businessarea_id, Process_ID from CaseTypesTable) SubProcessTbl
ON WORK.RequestSubProcess#1 = SubProcessTbl.subprocess_id
AND SubProcessTbl.businessarea_id = WORK.RequestBusinessArea#1
AND SubProcessTbl.process_id = WORK.RequestProcess#1
```

It's basically two queries which produce separate results, but each query includes data from the workTable. In the 2nd query, the workTable data is derived from the CaseTypesTable.

I essentially just want the businessarea, process, and subprocess fields to be included with the results of the first query.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ouch, you need to do some joins...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(SELECT top 100
w.pzInsKey,
w.pyID,
p.MacID,
p.OtherPartyID,
p.CustomerEmail,
a.AccountNumber,
a.AccountName,
a.AdviserCode,
a.AdviserName,
a.DealerCode,
a.DealerName,
a.PrimaryAccount,
a.ProductCategory,
a.ProductCode,
a.ProductDescription,
a.RegisteredState,
d.UDOCID
FROM workTable w
LEFT JOIN partyTable p
ON w.pzInsKey = p.pxInsIndexedKey
LEFT JOIN accountTable a
ON w.pzInsKey = a.pxInsIndexedKey
LEFT JOIN documentTable d
ON w.pyID = d.CaseID)
UNION 
(SELECT top 100 
ba.businessarea,
pr.process,
spr.subprocess
FROM workTable w

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID businessarea_id, Product businessarea from CaseTypesTable) BusinessAreaTbl ba
ON w.RequestBusinessArea#1 = ba.businessarea_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Process_ID, Process, Product_ID businessarea_id from CaseTypesTable) ProcessTbl pr
ON w.RequestProcess#1 = pr.process_id
AND pr.businessarea_id = w.RequestBusinessArea#1

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SubProcess_ID, SubProcess, Product_ID businessarea_id, Process_ID from CaseTypesTable) SubProcessTbl spr
ON w.RequestSubProcess#1 = spr.subprocess_id
AND spr.businessarea_id = w.RequestBusinessArea#1
AND spr.process_id = w.RequestProcess#1))
```

Use the keyword `UNION` to combine two or more seperate `SELECT` statements.